# Need steps to upgrade oracle database from 10g to 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, upgrade

I am newbie in oracle database administration. I have been told to upgrade the oracle 10g database to 11g. As i have never done this before i would like to get some easy and safe method to upgrade from 10g to 11g.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This document might be a good place to start:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/upgrade/11gr2-upgrade-methods-wp-2011-486336.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the guide. But as i said i need steps rather than article form of guide. A good step by step procedure would be appreciated.

Comment: Upgrading of a database server is a complex task dependent upon a range of factors that are not just specific to the software. This is why highly skilled DBA's are employed to perform them. Not knowing anything about your environment there is no way I could give you a step by step guide. My advice would be to ask a DBA who knows your setup for advice. Best of luck with this question though, I hope you get the answer you are seeking.

Comment: One step that I will give you though is the first one, ensure your database is fully backed up so that in the event of a catastrophic failure in the upgrade you can still revocer to your old version and your data will be intact. Best of luck.